# Get unique list in a column from values separated by commas in different rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I get unique values which are separated by commas in different rows into a column-list in EXCEL

**My Data**

```
Dallas, New York, Austin, Tokyo
Dallas, New York, Austin, Tokyo
London, Tokyo
Tokyo, Istanbul
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Dallas
New York
Austin
Tokyo
London
Istanbul
```

Answer (score 1):

**Manually**

1. Data > Text to Columns > Delimited > Next > Comma > Finish
2. Copy all the data from separate columns into one column
3. Select the column > Data > Remove Duplicates

---

**Automatically**

1. Open your sheet
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
3. Insert > Module
4. Paste this code:

```
Sub list_unique()
  Dim rngData As Range
  Dim c As Range
  Dim i As Long
  Dim arr() As String
  Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim key As Variant

  Set rngData = Range("A14:A17")
  For Each c In rngData
    arr = Split(c.Value, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
      dict(Trim(arr(i))) = 1
    Next
  Next
  i = 1
  For Each key In dict.Keys
    rngData(1).Offset(rngData.Rows.Count + i).Value = key
    i = i + 1
  Next

End Sub
```

5. In the code, change `Range("A14:A17")` with your actual range address where you have your data.
6. Hit <kbd>F5</kbd>

Comment: Your code never checks for duplicate entries.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - No need. Specifics of dictionaries is that duplicate keys cannot be included.

Comment: Ah, I see now what is happening.  Very clever  +1.  I had been specifically testing for duplicates.  And when I ran your code, because of embedded spaces in the data that I copy/pasted, there appeared to be some duplicates.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - Thank you! `Trim()` was in a wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

With data in column **A**, run this short VBA macro:

```
Sub Sundar()
    Dim s As String, c As Collection, k As Long

    Set c = New Collection
    k = 1

    s = Replace(Application.WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(",", True, Range("A:A")), " ", "")
    arr = Split(s, ",")

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each a In arr
        c.Add a, CStr(a)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Cells(k, 2).Value = a
            k = k + 1
        Else
            Err.Number = 0
        End If
    Next a
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would use vba, but to prove it can be done with a formula:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",,$A$2:$A$5),",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX($XFD:$XFD,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",,$A$2:$A$5))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)),AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($XFD$1:INDEX($XFD:$XFD,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",,$A$2:$A$5))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(,",",""))+1))/(COUNTIFS($B$1:B1,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",,$A$2:$A$5),",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX($XFD:$XFD,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",,$A$2:$A$5))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)))=0),1))
```

This will join all the strings then create an array of all the entries split on the `,` then cycle through passing the first to be found that already does not exist in the growing list.

A couple caveates:

1. This requires Office 365 or later
2. It is an array type formula and as such too many will slow down the calcs.
3. It is just plain hard to maintain.
4. It must be placed with at least one cell above it and that cell above address should replace the `$B$1:B1` paying attention to what is and what is not absolute.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Excel 2013 or later on Windows, there is a (relatively) short formula to perform this task using the [FILTERXML function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filterxml-function-4df72efc-11ec-4951-86f5-c1374812f5b7).

```
=UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A:A),",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s"))
```

`TEXTJOIN()` is used to combine every cell in `A:A` into a single string joined by commas.
`SUBSTITUTE()` is used to replace every comma with the tags `</s><s>`.
`FILTERXML()` is used to turn the long string into an array.
`UNIQUE()` is used to filter out just the unique values from that array.

If you want, you could wrap the entire thing in a `SORT()` function to get a *sorted* list.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I created an application based on you answer. This is the easiest solution. Just copy paste your data in the text area and click the run button.

[Here you can see a screenshot of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEeix.gif)

You can also change the separator using the combo box. Let me know if you have a question.

Here you have the boring way to do it. Using a VBA.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim countries As String
Dim arrayofcountries
Dim con As Integer

con = 0

For i = 2 To 5
countries = Cells(i, 1).Value

If (countries = "") Then
    ''Do nothing

Else
    arrayofcountries= Split(countries , ",")
    For Z = LBound(arrayofcountries) To UBound(arrayofcountries)

                        Cells(i + con, 3).Value = arrayofcountries(Z)
                        con = con + 1

    Next Z
 
End If

con = con - 1
Next i

End Sub
```

Just remove duplicates with Excel.

Comment: Your example doesn't create a unique list, the generated list, has duplicates.

Comment: That's why I said remove duplicates with Excel at the end (using the remove duplicates capability in Excel). After running the macro, just click remove duplicates. That's easiar and faster.